# change jtable's column hedding according different actionPerforms

Tags: swing

I have a Jtable extending AbstractTableModel,And I have differnt buttons in my form ,When click on different buttons differnt types of data is loaded in the table,I want to set suitable  column hedding on different click of buttons

Comment: please change "hedding" to heading or at least wedding.

Answer (score 0):

Since "different types of data" must be loaded to the JTable, you need different AbstractTableModels. myModelA, myModelB, myModelC etc.

You can set the appropriate model with:

```
  myTable.setModel(new myModelA());
```

and

```
  myTable.setModel(new myModelB());
```

etc, 
at the ActionListener - actionPerformed() of your buttons. Each model will provide headings for the appropriate data.